# Configure radius server via GUI in Cisco WLC

Tags: cisco, vlan, wlc, radius

My boss asked me to create a lobby administration for user authentication in a certain Virtual LAN. So I googled for it, and I found out that RADIUS server will work for this. And I've reached this step of configuring the RADIUS Authentication, and I'm stuck:

[image]

So I found out that I need to configure (activate?) the RADIUS server first in order to be able to do this. I googled again. There are two options I can understand:

1. I create my own RADIUS server using [FreeRadius](http://freeradius.org/).
2. Configure it on Cisco 5500 Series Wireless Controller. I'm not sure about this but my colleague told me that Cisco has provided RADIUS server for its users.

So I prefer the second option. The problem now is that I don't know how to configure the RADIUS server (to get the IP address and so on). I googled again, and all I found is the tutorial to do it using Command Line Interface (telnet, windows). Because I'm new at this stuff, my boss asked me to use only GUI. But I clicked everywhere in the web-browser interface I found nothing to get it.

So am I doing this wrong? Or Cisco doesn't support RADIUS server at all (so I have to choose the first option)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLCs are *NOT* Radius Servers, you need an external Radius server and then point the WLCs to it

The page you are on right now is to configure credentials to actually be able to query the external radius server: IP Address & Ports, Shared Secret, and other connectivity options.

Cisco Radius servers are called ACS (secure Access Control System) and to TACACS as well

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are most likely looking for is known as local authentication. This is implemented using Lightweight EAP, or "LEAP."

Essentially you create a local database of users on the controller, and this database is queried directly when authenticating clients. Instead of configuring another type of EAP such as EAP-TLS or PEAP and specifying a RADIUS server, you configure the SSID to use LEAP. The specifics of this vary between controllers, but with the above information, finding more specific configuration instructions should be much easier.

Comment: To be clear, LEAP is an authentication method as part of EAP, so technically EAP-LEAP.  However it should also be noted that LEAP is considered to be one of the less secure authentication methods, so take this into consideration before you choose to implement it.